# Grub 2.02 on vacation after first boot - Arch on mSATA USB

Tags: boot, usb, ssd, grub, arch-linux

I have a freshly installed Arch Linux LVM inside a [LUKS](https://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/) container all nestled on an external USB SSD. Although I have no problem with the Arch system itself, I do have a problem with Grub.

After the initial installation, I can boot perfectly normal without issue. Even logged in and configured my desktop a bit. Shutdown the system. Reboot, no Grub!! Not even a rescue shell.

So I go back to the LiveUSB, open my LUKS container, `remount`, `chroot`, `grub-install` (without modifying anything), `exit`, `umount`, `shutdown`.

Then, I can boot perfectly normal without issue. But, as soon as I shut it down and try to restart it, Grub is not working. I can do this any number of times with the same effect. I don’t notice any changes when I am initially booted into installed system or `chroot`ed into the system.

My `fstab` and `grub` are both configured to use UUID. But, even still if it wasn’t properly configured (I wouldn't be able to boot it initially) and I should atleast get a Grub rescue shell or Arch rescue shell. But, I don’t get anything on the second boot.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Additional info:

- **Host computer:** Surface Pro 1 (secure boot disabled)
- **USB SSD:** Samsung 840EVO msata (mushkin Atlas 3.0 housing)
- **LiveUSB:** Generic 2GB

GPT, UEFI (has a BIOS partition but I haven’t set up GRUB BIOS at all):

- **PART 1** - DATA 8GB 0700
- **PART 2** - BIOS 2MB ef02
- **PART 3** - UEFI 250MB ef00 /boot
- **PART 4** - ARCH 110GB 8e00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure how to mark this as solved but I did find a solution and thought I should post it. Probably not the most space efficient method but it worked.

The initial `grubx64.efi` was inside `/boot/EFI/arch` directory. I made two other directories `/boot/EFI/arch/Boot` and `/boot/EFI/Boot` and copied this to both directories.

I also made a copy and renamed it to `bootx64.efi` and copied it to every directory containing the `grubx64.efi`.

I'm not sure which one is pulling the workload but I am booting 100% now.

Comment: Cool, says I can't accept my own answer until tomorrow. I guess I'll have to do it later. Thanks.